# The difference between "Geschäft", "Unternehmen", "Betrieb" and "Firma"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

The following words all mean *business* in English, but what is the difference between *Geschäft*, *Unternehmen*, *Betrieb* and *Firma*?

Comment: Sorry I am new to the site and not quite sure how to use this. How come my question is different than:  http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25988/frei-vs-gratis-vs-umsonst-vs-kostenlos or http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/whats-the-difference-between-sonstige-and-andere

Comment: Geschäft is a store, Unternehmen is a business, Betrieb too but may be part of a bigger Unternehmen. Firma is originally latin and describes only the name of a business, but is used by the majority when they actually mean Unternehmen.

Comment: Actually, *Geschäft* can also be used for business, as in *... gehört zu unserem täglichen Geschäft* (*... is part of our daily business*). *Store* could also be called *Laden*.

Comment: Why was this closed? Most dictionaries just use "business" as the definition and don't explain the subtle differences. I'm not sure this question deserves such a cursory answer.

Comment: I am confused as well, but it is alright. I found out Reddit r/german sub group is more friendly. I am asking question there now instead. Thank you for your help.